# What is better to install to virtualization on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, webserver, xen

i have home server and i want virtualize all my hosts (web,radio, tracker, file server etc) to use more then one OS.

So for host OS i want install Ubuntu-server on HDD 500gbx2 Raid 1.

i want to use virtualization software.  there is variants KVM, XEN, Virch, Vmware ESXi (free licence if possible) and of cause i need a web interface for it.

can you please advice me what will be better for me (as noobie).

right now i got server's host (os that was before)  on debian transfered to vmware machine it will my web guest virtual machine (as i understand i need convert it later).

i know ubuntu have a Maas technology can i use it for configure virtual machines ??

Comment: MaaS (Metal as a Service) is a datacenter-level technology that uses hardware features like IPMI or AMT to remotely manage the installation of operating systems to *physical* servers, allowing to combine some of the "cloud-like" flexibility with bare-metal efficiency. It is not really applicable to the situation where you have just one physical server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but if you want to get into virtualization on Linux, I really recommend checking out Proxmox.

You can't run Ubuntu as the Host OS, at least it's not recommended, but you get Debian as Host OS instead and it it's what Ubuntu is based on, so it's not too foreign.

Proxmox has an excellent web interface, and a great community and as such it's a good place to start and learn.

https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Installation for more info.

Comment: yeah, thanx for reply i will try. just need to know it works with raid? backup/restore machines

Comment: just look at proxmox. so its realy good support raid and support backup, also very good works with vnc and remote control UI. so i think its difenetely what i need. today will install and check on server. thanx again for your advice